# Creating trackable QR codes

Tags: google-analytics, qr-code, wechat

I'm having trouble understanding how to track qr codes in general with wechat if this was just a QR that leads to my personal website I would just do say `mysite.com?utm_source=marketing&utm_medium=Tyler` and I would be able to see if because `mysite` is attached to my Google analytics account.

However with wechat the URL I have to use for the qr code looks something like this `http://weixin.qq.com/q/02dz0Vxg6Weq110dddd00g03c` as the QR URL The problem I have here is there is no way for me to track that URL since it is not my domain.

Do I need to have the QR code go to my site and setup a redirect there that leads to the wechat URL?